# Python code inside HTML file not working (Django)

Tags: python, html, django

I have two templates one is called index.html and the other cart.html.
The index.html file accepts python code but if I put exactly the same code in cart.html Python is not recognised.
I am working with Django. How can I fix this?

index.html where python code works

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <th>List of car parts available:</th>
        </tr>
        {% for product in products_list %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
          <td>
            {% if product.in_cart == False %}
                <a href=""></a>
          </td>
          <td>{{ product.ordered }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

cart.html where python code doesn't work

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <th>List of car parts available:</th>
        </tr>
        {% for product in products_list %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
          <td>
            {% if product.in_cart == False %}
                <a href=""></a>
          </td>
          <td>{{ product.ordered }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

views.py

```py
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.template import loader
    from .models import Product
    # from django.shortcuts import render


    def index(request):
        products_list = Product.objects.all()
        template = loader.get_template('products/index.html')
        context = {'products_list': products_list}
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

    def cart(request):
        cart_list = Product.objects.filter(in_cart == True)
        template = loader.get_template('products/cart.html')
        context = {'cart_list': cart_list}
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to help unless you provide sufficient detail about the problem. We cannot see your code or setup or anything. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: show your code .

Comment: Sorry, I just added screenshots of the 2 files

Comment: Well, don't. Post code as text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The context data you are passing to your template doesn't match the variable you're calling in the template.

From your views.py file:

```
def cart(request):
    cart_list = Product.objects.filter(in_cart == True)
    template = loader.get_template('products/cart.html')
    context = {'cart_list': cart_list}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

And then in your cart.html file:

```
    {% for product in products_list %}
```

You need to change the cart.html for loop to be `{% for product in cart_list %}`, since `cart_list` is the variable you've added to the context.

Answer (score 0):

with django, code only works inside html if the html file is processed by django - that means you have to use one of django's html template processing tools.

More commonly used are: `render_to_string` or `get_template` to get a template object followed by the `.render()` method

Check the [django template documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I just added a screenshot of my views, in which I specify to get a template for product/cart.html. But still not working..

Comment: Please, don't add screenshots. Add the actual text. @NicoBar it seems your template that is not working (`cart.html`) is trying to use a variable named `products_list` however the code only passes a variable named `cart_list`, so I guess that is your problem. If not, you should provide (as text) the full error you're getting, with all information and trackeback, along with full code as text.